# TFS Sharepoint Integration no SharePoint Web Applications

Tags: tfs, integration

I am trying to integrate Team Foundation Server with SharePoint.
I am doing this on a laptop with SharePoint on a Virtual Machine
with Windows Server 2012 and TFS on the real machine with Windows 8.1

Following this [this link](http://www.infotechguyz.com/TeamFoundationServer/TeamFoundationServerandSharePointIntegration.html) I read:

```
To allow access between Team Foundation Server and a SharePoint Web app
1.On TFS application tier Server, launch administration console for Team Foundation.
2.Click on SharePoint Web apps.
```

Unfortunately  there is not **SharePoint Web apps** on my TFS Server console.
Is it because I am using Windows 8.1 or do I need to have SharePoint installed on the TFS server as well?

Comment: did you install the extensions for SharePoint products on sharepoint server?

Comment: Yes, I did and on the SharePoint machine I granted access to TFS as well with the TFS console.

Comment: can you access the sharepoint sites from the tfs machine?

Comment: Yes I can do it. But TFS should be on a Windows server machine maybe?

Comment: that is what i read so far. check this one, http://nakedalm.com/integrate-sharepoint-2013-with-team-foundation-server-2013/ I would say configure another VM and Install/configure TFS their and then integrate with SharePoint